# BSOD upon loading game

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, bsod

I am playing Uncharted Waters Online. The game will give me a BSOD upon loading. I have no means to rollback my restore point.

Posting my minidmp report here, hopefully someone can enlighten me on what to do.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\120816-51293-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7601.23569.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.161007-0600
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03652000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03894730
Debug session time: Thu Dec  8 00:39:19.303 2016 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:07:23.505
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.......................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
......
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck F4, {3, fffffa8006b40060, fffffa8006b40340, fffff800039ccb70}

ETW minidump data unavailable
Probably caused by : csrss.exe

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, Process
Arg2: fffffa8006b40060, Terminating object
Arg3: fffffa8006b40340, Process image file name
Arg4: fffff800039ccb70, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------

ETW minidump data unavailable

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.23569.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.161007-0600

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  0304

BIOS_DATE:  11/17/2010

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK Computer INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P8H67-M

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: fffffa8006b40060

BUGCHECK_P3: fffffa8006b40340

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff800039ccb70

KERNEL_LOG_FAILING_PROCESS:  (null)

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  csrss.exe

IMAGE_NAME:  csrss.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MODULE_NAME: csrss

FAULTING_MODULE: 0000000000000000 

EXCEPTION_CODE: (Win32) 0x7037060 (117665888) - <Unable to get error code text>

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x7037060 - <Unable to get error code text>

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: d47

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 6'00000000 (cache) 6'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  ADMIN-PC

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  12-08-2016 09:10:36.0029

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`03fbd9d8 fffff800`03a56852 : 00000000`000000f4 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`06b40060 fffffa80`06b40340 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`03fbd9e0 fffff800`03a1409b : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`07037060 fffffa80`06b40060 00000000`00000001 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x92
fffff880`03fbda20 fffff800`0397d454 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000890 fffffa80`06b40060 00000000`00000008 : nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x27296
fffff880`03fbda70 fffff800`036c1693 : 00000000`00000890 fffffa80`07037060 fffffa80`06b40060 fffffa80`05a6fc60 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0x284
fffff880`03fbdae0 00000000`77c8bffa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`03dce808 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x77c8bffa


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  e9460336222f4471d8ae88a3d24ad7df3aff8ef1

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  78fb9c444b7807cd1bd5e414e2ce7cd6e803d8b6

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f08ac56120cad14894587db086f77ce277bfae84

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_TERMINATED_BY_GVOnline.bin_7037060

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_TERMINATED_BY_GVOnline.bin_7037060

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0xF4_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_TERMINATED_BY_GVOnline.bin_7037060

TARGET_TIME:  2016-12-07T16:39:19.000Z

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  1000

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-10-07 22:58:59

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  161007-0600

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_ldr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.23569.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.161007-0600

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 680

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xf4_csrss.exe_bugcheck_critical_process_terminated_by_gvonline.bin_7037060

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {f1b32ccd-394d-98d3-4e2e-90bf069faaf2}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Answer (score 0):

This text says it is a problem with a driver:

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT
```

It's not clear to me which one. But, given that you are loading a game, it's almost certainly either the graphics card or hard disk causing the issue. Small chance it's the sound card.

1) look for newer graphics card drivers and sound card driver (from manufacturer's websites), install them if they exist, see if it fixes the problem ([NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx), [ATI](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download))

2) [check the hard disk for errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2641432) - could be loading crappy data from a damaged sector when you start the game. In this case, it's probably time for a new disk as problems will only get worse.

Comment: csrss.exe is windows instructions for graphics so it's likely your graphics drivers.  It might also be worth checking for viruses / malware.